# Frame pointer optimization always on with vs 2010 (and later)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

I have a generated c source code that seems like this:

```
void LCERCA_OGGETTO_AUTO();

void LCERCA_OGGETTO_AUTO()
{
   MyApi();
}
```

Then I compile the code with frame pointer optimization off /Oy-. All flags are:

`/c /Os /Oi /Gs /O2 /MT /Gy /Gd /Oy-`

So I aspected to find the "standard" function proloque:

```
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

but instead nothing!

I need this prologue to reconstruct the stack at runtime, to check if the code calling `MyApi` is inside LCERCA_OGGETTO_AUTO or other function.

I miss some compiler flags?

I edited the question to clarify the context.
We used a propietary language and we translate our source in c.
In order to create a debugger at source code level, we instrument the generated c code  with calls, once for every line of source code:

```
static void LLEGGI_OGGETTO()
{
    TraceDebug2("LEGGI_OGGETTO", 0, FALSE );
    BCTracePrint5(220, "DFX_AREA,COD_AREA"); 
    strncpy (PD->DFX_AREA_BC, FNTR(PS->COD_AREA_BC), 10);
    BCTracePrint5(221, "DFX_PRODOT,COD_PRODOT"); 
    strncpy (PD->DFX_PRODOT_BC, FNTR(PS->COD_PRODOT_BC), 10);
    BCTracePrint5(222, "DFX_PROGET,COD_PROGET"); 
    strncpy (PD->DFX_PROGET_BC, FNTR(PS->COD_PROGET_BC), 10);
    BCTracePrint5(224, "OGG_TIPO"); 
    if ((*(PS->OGG_TIPO_BC))==0)
    {
        BCTracePrint4(225); 
        LCERCA_OGGETTO_AUTO();
        BCTracePrint4(226); 
    } 
     else {
        BCTracePrint4(227); 
        LCERCA_OGGETTO_PRECISO();
        BCTracePrint4(228); 

    }


    BCTracePrint4(230); 
    TraceDebug2("LEGGI_OGGETTO", 1, FALSE );
}
```

The code is "filled" with call to BCTracePrintXX functions where the debug engine lives.
 BCTracePrintXX functions use __fastcall convention to minimize the impact on performance.
 In order to provide the "step over / step in" we need to know inside BCTracePrintXX function if the caller is in the same stack frame of previuos call. The idea is to collect ebp value inside BCTracePrintXX. We can do this because we use __fastcall convention so we have total control of registry use.
For this reason we have to disable the frame pointer optimization.

Comment: Hard to see what "nothing" looks like.  It is somewhat guessable,  if you insist on a stack frame for this function then you have to disable the function inlining optimization.  One-liners like that always disappear.  /Ob0 is the sledgehammer, `__declspec(noinline)` is the fine-tuned instrument applicable to individual functions.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks for your answer, Tomorrow i'll try your suggestion. Probably I have to explain better what I wanted to do and what I aspected.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I found that the compiler options that control the  optimizations are not so orthogonal as I supposed. In particular it seems that if you have `/O2` optimization enabled you have and cannot disable the frame pointer omission optimization, ie:
`/O2 /Oy-` doesn't disable FPO. For this I chose a different approach, where I re-create the call stack in a simpler way.